# Adding vertical lines through median values of cumulative distributions (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot2 to plot two cumulative distributions on a single plot. This is straightforward using the example from `?stat_ecdf`. My difficulty is in adding vertical lines through the median value of each distribution.

It's easy enough to do this with a single distribution:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(rnorm(100, 5, 10), rnorm(200, 0, 10)),
  g = as.factor(c(rep(1, 100), rep(2, 200))))

ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
  stat_ecdf() + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = median(x)))
```

But I can't figure out an easy way to add vertical lines for multiple distributions. I've tried the following without success:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, colour = g)) +
  stat_ecdf() +   
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = median(x), colour = g))
```

I can sort of get the desired result by assembling the plot in stages:

```
p <- ggplot(df[df$g == 1, ], aes(x)) +
  stat_ecdf() + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = median(x)))

p + 
  stat_ecdf(data = df[df$g == 2, ]) +
  geom_vline(data = df[df$g == 2, ], aes(xintercept = median(x)))
```

But this seems like an untidy way of doing it and also leaves me to set the different line colours by hand.

Surely there's a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

> ```
> ggplot(df, aes(x, colour = g)) +
>     stat_ecdf() +   
>     geom_vline(aes(xintercept = median(x[g==1]), color=g[g==1])) + 
>     geom_vline(aes(xintercept = median(x[g==2]), color=g[g==2]))
> ```

By adding a second `geom_vline` argument and specifying which group each line and color is referring to, you can get two lines with the corresponding colors. Hope that helps!

Comment: This is helpful as I didn't know you could subset using square brackets like this in ggplot2! Unfortunately, while this answer worked with my original example data, it gives an error with my real data: _arguments imply differing number of rows_. I've edited my example data to reflect the differing number of values in each level.

Comment: @Nicholas Edit both `geom_vline` objects by removing the bracket subsetting from the `median` and `color` arguments and instead including `data=df[df$g==1,],` (or `data=df[df$g==2,],` for the second) before your aes arguments. This will subset the data for each line and allow each to be different lengths. The full lines should look like this: `geom_vline(data=df[df$g==1,], aes(xintercept = median(x), colour = g))` & `geom_vline(data=df[df$g==2,], aes(xintercept = median(x), colour = g))`